# Desktop background Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, desktop-background

I have upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04. I have a problem with my desktop background.

I can not change the background picture from system settings. When I click a picture, it will not pick it.

When I have login via "GDM" it seems that pixels from GDM is transfer to my desktop background.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and this solution worked for me. Thanks Tanasis.

Answer (score 4):

Try in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```